# WPF culture change

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create an application that, when a button is clicked, changes the application's language. I have multiple resx files, so far for Portuguese and English. I have a statement that changes the current culture when the button is clicked, but it doesn't work. However, if I put it before the initialize statement, the culture does change and it initializes to the language I want. 
I've looked online for ways to reload the project/window, but I couldn't find any answers that fix the problem.

Comment: What is the relationship between the title and the description of your question?

Comment: Whoops I don't know why that is the title, I definitely did not set that...

Comment: you may want to take a look at https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension It supports runtime instantaneous culture changes